# Comicbook shader for real time with three.js (cel shading)

Tags: three.js

How can I achieve a similar effect (cel shading, comicbook) with three.js like the example?

Are there any lessons or example code?

**Example**
http://demonraid.com/wolvie2/

Comment: The example you link to is one i haven't seen before but has a human readable scene initialization and is the best example I have seen. See line 319 in http://demonraid.com/wolvie2/lib/scene.js  Line 319 defines the shader material. Line 413 applies the shader material to everything on scene. This works because the example takes advantage of THREE.Object3d.SkinnedMesh. He sets the object to skinning true and applies the shader to those meshes.

Comment: I am afraid the site referenced no longer works.

Answer (score 11):

The example you provide is very complex with several effects that make up the comic-like looks.

But if you can settle for a simpler look, then Three.js provides a ready made cel shader that you can combine with an outline effect: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_variations_toon

The material is documented here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshToonMaterial

And the outline effect is here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/effects/OutlineEffect.js